# RMagick Draw Image using Array RGB

Tags: ruby, image, rgb, rmagick

I have an array of `RGB` values for individual pixels of a digital result that has analyzed an image.  The array represents rows of individual pixels, which make up the image.  The resulting image shows me what groups of pixels qualify as being "hot spots".

I'm using `RMagick` in `Ruby` and I'm wanting to build this result image from the arrays of pixels that I have.  I'm not clear as to how I can import that array as the visual pixel colours. An example:

```
imagepixels = [
        [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [255,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [255,0,0], [255,0,0], [0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [255,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]],
        [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
        ]
```

I can't seem to get any methods to work from `RMagick`, but I have found this one, which I'm confused over:

```
.import_pixels(blob, columns, rows, depth, map, format = 'png') ⇒ MiniMagick::Image
```

Is there an easier way to get these pixels into the `Magick` object, then write the file?  Or how can I get this done, given the array that I already have?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [constitute](https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#constitute) method will serve your needs.